# How can I mass remove categories in “Include in Navigation Menu” in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have added way to many items inside of my subcategories into Magento.

I want to some how keep hold of CTRL+/CMD key or the ALT key or some other method to mass edit them and mass Select the option to NO - I do not want these in the Navigation menu.

I do not want to use MySQL EAV updating approach - there should be a way or plugin to do this through the admin panel I hope ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Load Up Magento Core
define('MAGENTO', realpath('/'));

require_once(MAGENTO . 'app/Mage.php');

$app = Mage::app();

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("gt" => 1))
 ->setOrder('entity_id')
 ;

foreach($categories as $category) {
 echo $category->getId() . "\t" . $category->getName() . "\n";
 $category->setIncludeInMenu(0);
 $category->save();
}
```

Check above. Inspire..

Comment: Be careful! This solution will reset the described option !!!in all categories!!!

Comment: Thats why i told him to inspire.. :)

Answer (score 0):

update catalog_category_entity_int cci
inner join eav_attribute a on a.attribute_id = cci.attribute_id
set cci.value = 0
where a.attribute_code = 'include_in_menu'

remove all categories from include in menu.